# x86 addl vs subl

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, x86, clang

I just notice that Clang compiles this statement (without any optimization, of course):

```
--x; /* int x; */
```

into:

```
addl    $4294967295, %ecx       ## imm = 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Why? Is there any advantage of using `addl` instead of the "obvious" `subl`? Or is it just an implementation fact?

What tricks me is that this one:

```
x -= 1;
```

becomes:

```
subl    $1, %eax
```

Clang info:

```
Apple clang version 3.0 (tags/Apple/clang-211.12) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: It's probably just the implementation, and could change with optimization level. What's more interesting is that it doesn't use `dec`, which may be an optimization because `dec` doesn't change as many status flags so it is dependent on previous instructions.

Comment: gcc produces the same code for both `x--` and `x=-1` using `subl`. Interestingly, it uses `xorl` if I enable `-O3`.

Comment: There is no advantage, and there is no disadvantage. Both are 3 bytes and have the same performance characteristics.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: For modern processors `dec` has either the same speed or is slower then `add`/`sub`, so using it as an optimization doesn't really make sense (for speed at least, it might offer a benefit when it comes to executable size)

Comment: @ughoavgfhw On many proccessors `dec` and `inc` are actually slower, because they do change only a _part_ of the status flag register and so introduce partial register dependencies when used together with other arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior has to do with the way clang handles pre-decrement as opposed to binary operators like sub-and-assign. Note that I will just try to explain, at the clang level, why you see this behavior. I don't know why it was chosen to implement it this way but I guess it was just for ease of implementation.

All functions I reference here can be found in class `ScalarExprEmitter` inside  `lib/CodeGen/CGExprScalar.cpp`.

Pre/post decrement/increment are all handled the same way by the function `EmitScalarPrePostIncDec`: an LLVM `add` instruction is emitted with either `1` or `-1` as second argument, depending on the expression being an increment or a decrement respectively.

Therefore,

```
--x
```

will end up, in the LLVM IR, as something like

```
add i32 %x, -1
```

which, quite naturally, translates to x86 as something like

```
add $0xffffffff, %ecx
```

Binary operators, on the other hand, are all handled differently. In your case,

```
x -= 1
```

will be handled by `EmitCompoundAssign` which in turn calls `EmitSub`. Something like the following LLVM IR will be emitted:

```
sub i32 %x, 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and source references. That's what I was looking for, it makes sense and proves that it's in implementation consequence.